# Infinite while loop issue with a conditional operation function

Tags: c, loops, while-loop, conditional-statements, assert

My code gets stuck in an infinite loop. The current number is halved, When the next number is even, the function should execute 2n+1. If odd, it should execute 3n + 1. Once either operation is executed it should halve it again and loop until n = 1. Here is the code:

```c
#include "stdio.h"
#include "assert.h" // ?

long int hailstone(long int k);

int main(void) {
  long int n = 77;
  hailstone(n);
  
  return 0;
}

long int hailstone(long int k) {
  while (k != 1) {
    k = k/2;
    if (k % 2 == 0) {
          k = 2 * k + 1;
          printf("%lu", k);
    
    } else if (k % 2 != 0) {
          k = 3 * k + 1;
          printf("%lu", k);
      
    } else if (k == 1) {
          printf("blue sky!");
    }
  }
}
```

Would a particular assertion help the compiler execute the code as expected?

Comment: Do you realise you have a `if (k == 1)` inside `while (k != 1)`? And also that the same `if (k == 1)` is in an `else` branch to both being even and odd?

Comment: `k` will never be `1` by the time you test it in the `while(k != 1)` loop, and the other test `if(k == 1)` is never reached.

Comment: Using very basic printf debugging (basically simply looking at your output) you should notice that `k` is oscillating between 77 and 38. 77 is divided by 2 which results in 38. Then you calculate 2 * 38 + 1 which gets you back to 77. There is something wrong with your algorithm.

Comment: Perhaps you mean to store k in a temporary variable (say l), and do your computations on l instead of k, and keep deviding k by 2. And then consider what will happen when someone calls hailstone with a value less than 1.

Comment: [ref](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/hailstone-numbers/) may help.  I suspect "When the next number is even, the function should execute 2n+1." is incorrect.

Comment: I had to blink when I noticed my comment misquoted your code: rolled back. Please don't ask shifting-sand questions!

Comment: You are handling a special case as one of the general cases and just need to rearrange the code a little bit to catch the special case separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand your code

If the value of n is pair ,you make this **n/2** , if not you display **3*n+1**

My code :

output : 116,58,29,44,22,11,17,26,13,20,10,5,8,4,2,1

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "assert.h" // ?


long int hailstone(long int k);

int main(void)
{
    long int n = 77;
    hailstone(n);
    return 0;
}

long int hailstone(long int k)
{
    while (k != 1)
    {
       if ( k % 2 ==0)
       {
           printf("k = %lu\n",k/2);
           k/=2;   // k=k/2
       }
       else
       {
           k = 3 * k + 1;
       }
    }
        printf("blue sky!\n");
    
}
```

Comment: The final test is unnecessary. You can only get there if `k == 1`.

Comment: @cornuz : it's done

Answer (score 2):

Your code is overly complicated and wrong.

It basically boils down to this (try it):

```
long int hailstone(long int k) {
  while (k != 1) {
    k = k/2;
    printf("k divided by 2: %lu\n", k);
    if (k % 2 == 0) {
      k = 2 * k + 1;
      printf("k after k = 2 * k + 1 %lu\n", k);
    }
  }
}
```

Output:

```
k divided by 2: 38
k after k = 2 * k + 1 77
k divided by 2: 38
k after k = 2 * k + 1 77
k divided by 2: 38
k after k = 2 * k + 1 77
...
```

Just applying the [definitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture#Statement_of_the_problem) blindly:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void hailstone(long int k);

int main(void) {
  long int n = 77;
  hailstone(n);    
  return 0;
}

long int func(long int k)
{
  if (k % 2 == 0)
    return k / 2;
  else
    return 3 * k + 1;
}

void hailstone(long int k) {
  while (k != 1)
  {
    printf("k = %d\n", k);
    k = func(k);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tested out this code and it runs as expected. Mine was over-complicated. When running the code with compiler flags: Wall, Wpedantic, Wextra, I get a warning on line 25: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
   25 | }

Comment: @JoeP the warning is normal, it should be `void hailstone(long int k)` instead of `long int hailstone(long int k)`.

Answer (score 0):

> Would a particular assertion help the compiler execute the code as expected?

No

Asserts are used to STOP execution for certain events.